# encoding a form into an email body with python

Tags: python, forms, email

I am trying to create a basic webapp in python that allows to ask for information via a form and email I am trying to encode the content of the form fields into the email body, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I get many different type of errors, in particular, the following when I try to json the content: TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable

```
    @app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        form = Init(request.form)
        if request.method == 'GET': # make sure the method used is define above
            return render_template('home.html', form = form), logging.warning("you are under the home page now using GET, well done bacco ")
        elif request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        # the following are the data from the init form
        name = form.name.data                           
        telefono = form.telefono.data
        email = form.email.data
        messaggio = form.messaggio.data

    # defining a new variable taking as input the values from the init form
        mymsg=[{ 
            "name": name, 
            "telefono": telefono, 
            "email" : email, 
            "messaggio" : messaggio
            }]
        # insert the list into the mongo db
        x = mycol.insert_many(mymsg), print("inserting this user: ", mymsg, "in the database called ", mycol)
        json_list = json.dumps(mymsg)
        msg = Message('New message from: ', sender='xxxxxxx@gmail.com', recipients=['xxxxxxx@gmail.com'], body = mymsg)
        msg.body = 'Messaggio: ', json_list
        mail.send(msg)
        return render_template('home.html', form = form), print("you are under the home page now using POST, data are sent to database")
```

Answer (score 0):

When the method `insert_many` is called, PyMongo will automatically adds a `_id` field typed **ObjectId** to all your documents, i.e. `mymsg`(see this [link](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#writes-and-ids) for reference).

That's why `json_list = json.dumps(mymsg)` gives the error.

For handling json encoding/decoding of BSON documents, you can use [json_util](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html).

Hope it helps.